# QSpinbox display 0.1 steps

Tags: qt, qspinbox

is there a way to get my spin box to be able to be adjusted in 0.1 value steps?

obviously minimum 0 maximum 90 but the single step I can only seem to modify this by 1.

could someone explain to me how to be able to modify this by 0.1?

Answer (score 3):

You want show double so you need QDoubleSpinBox.

Use `setSingleStep(0.1)` to do this.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdoublespinbox.html#singleStep-prop